# DoDirectPayment fails with an Internal error

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I created a business account (other than the default one created as facilitator) on sandbox and checked that the status of 'PayPal payments Pro' is 'live'. Used the API credentials specified in Profile->API Credentials screen. Username: sushishPunya_api1.gmail.com

I created another test account (personal) and used the credit card details specified in Profile->Funding screen (4952729234475105, Visa, 4/2018)

When I ran the DoDirectPayment NVP sample code(java), I get the following error:

{"map":{"L_LONGMESSAGE0":"Internal Error","VERSION":"86","BUILD":"5908853","L_ERRORCODE0":"10001","AMT":"12.00","ACK":"Failure","CORRELATIONID":"e5808c8712605","TIMESTAMP":"2013-05-09T08:07:36Z","L_SEVERITYCODE0":"Error","L_SHORTMESSAGE0":"Internal Error","CURRENCYCODE":"USD"}}

---

I'm calling it with the following input:

("Sale","12","Visa", "4952729234475105","042018","000", "Punya", "AK", "Elcmanio Real", "Sunnyvale", "CA", "94085", "US");

---

And here is the code:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2005, 2008 PayPal, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * DoDirectPayment NVP example; last modified 08MAY23. 
 *
 * Process a credit card payment.  
 */
package com.nvp.codegenerator;

import com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPDecoder;
import com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPEncoder;
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.APIProfile;
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.ProfileFactory;
import com.paypal.sdk.services.NVPCallerServices;
/**
 * PayPal Java SDK sample code
 */
public class DoDirectPayment 
{

    private NVPCallerServices caller = null;

    public NVPDecoder DoDirectPaymentCode(String paymentAction,String amount,String cardType,
                                String acct,String expdate,String cvv2, String firstName,
                                String lastName, String street, String city, String state, 
                                String zip, String countryCode)
    {
        NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
        NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

        try
        {

            caller = new NVPCallerServices();
        APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
            /*
             WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
             Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
             Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
             encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
             that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
             */
        // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, API operation and version.
            profile.setAPIUsername("sushishPunya_api1.gmail.com");
            profile.setAPIPassword("1366042621");
            profile.setSignature("AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A2VBZp4Zla5Y8mvvCUzzG2TrztxZ");
            /*profile.setAPIUsername("sdk-three_api1.sdk.com");
        profile.setAPIPassword("QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q");
        profile.setSignature("AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ"); */

            profile.setEnvironment("sandbox");
            profile.setSubject("");
            caller.setAPIProfile(profile);

            //encoder.add("VERSION", "86");
            encoder.add("VERSION", "51.0");
            encoder.add("METHOD","DoDirectPayment");

        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
            encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",paymentAction);
            encoder.add("AMT",amount);
            encoder.add("CREDITCARDTYPE",cardType);     
            encoder.add("ACCT",acct);                       
            encoder.add("EXPDATE",expdate);
            encoder.add("CVV2",cvv2);
            encoder.add("FIRSTNAME",firstName);
            encoder.add("LASTNAME",lastName);                                       
            encoder.add("STREET",street);
            encoder.add("CITY",city);   
            encoder.add("STATE",state);         
            encoder.add("ZIP",zip); 
            encoder.add("COUNTRYCODE",countryCode);

        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
            String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
            String NVPResponse =(String) caller.call(NVPRequest);
            decoder.decode(NVPResponse);
            String strAck = decoder.get("ACK");
            String trasID = decoder.get("TRANSACTIONID");
            System.out.println("trasID");
            if(strAck !=null && !(strAck.equals("Success") || strAck.equals("SuccessWithWarning"))) {
                // do error processing
                  System.out.println("\n########## CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call failed ##########\n");
            } else {

                //success
                 System.out.println("\n########## CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call passed ##########\n");
            }

        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decoder;
    }

}
```

---

Any idea what went wrong?

Thanks,
Punya

Comment: Can you provide log the actual API request that you are sending over with variables and values populated so that I can look at what you are sending further. What endpoint is your script submitting the data to? Most likely it has something to do with what you are passing over.

Comment: Yes. I figured out the solution. Passing amount as 12.00 instead of 12 solved the problem :-)